# Simplifying a large expression (just for subtraction and addition)

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions

Consider a large expression which contains terms like

```
a/x+b/x^2+c x + d x^4 +...-b/x^2 +h x -a/x +...
```

I want to find limit of the expression when x goes to zero. Because the expression is very huge, using Limit[exp,x->0] doesn't help and takes very very large time. Then, I decided to put x=0 and print the value of expression, but it gives `1/0 error`. It happens because Mathematica doesn't cancel terms like a/x and -a/x.

What is an efficient way to force MM to cancel these terms? I wanted to use simplify and then put x=0, but it also takes to much time for MM to simplify the expression. Could any one help me?

Comment: Do you know for sure that this expressions are polynomials in `x` (with negative powers of `x` allowed)? Then you could use `CoefficientList` on the summands and add up the `CoefficientList`s of the results...

Comment: I am sure that negative powers of x exist. @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: That was not my question.

Comment: There is no result. What I get is 1/0 error @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: Is there any way to expand an expression but without negative powers?

Comment: If you can put a copy of your notebook with the exact correct expression that you are working on somewhere and leave a link so others can grab a copy and look at it and perhaps suggest some way to make progress then you might have a chance. Otherwise "it is huge and doesn't work and how do I fix it" gives very very little for anyone to work on.

Comment: Try using Series, e.g., `Series[expr, {x, 0, 0}]` or `Series[expr, {x, Infinity, 0}]`

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
Collect[yourExpression, x]
```

and see if that will be a sufficiently fast way to group together similar x and thus get those to cancel, but without taking the time need to `Simplify` or `Limit` each of which need to do a lot more work than just grouping together similar powers of x.

But without being able to see your actual expression this is still just guesswork.